# Video not playing in Firefox on Mac

Tags: mac, firefox, video

I open the this link [Erlang](https://www.infoq.com/presentations/joe-armstrong-erlang-qcon08) which have a video . But it will not play . I recently reinstalled my mac, Iam beginner to Mac. I dont know why this video not playing in mac. But the same video play in firefox on another linux based machine. Please guide me to solve this problem

Comment: There is a dedicated community for Mac questions, please ask there. https://apple.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, please refrain from asking Apple-related questions [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) as there is a dedicated community for those questions.

But, I'll help you anyway. If it doesn't work on different devices (i've tried it myself), I've came to the conclusion that it is a faulty video. Maybe it doesn't exist on the host server or the video is encoded wrong. All in all - I've tried it on Chrome on Windows 7, you've tried it on Firefox on Mac OS, and in Firefox on another Linux-based machine. (my only question is what OS is on the Linux-based machine...).

Thanks,
**-Dan**